# Why Quarians still wear their suits and masks on their homeworld?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I did some missions on the Quarian's home world. In previous games I found out that:

> Quarians wear suits and masks, so that they don't get infected by the 'air' in stations and other planets. But now doing missions on their planet Rannoch, Tali and even other of her race are still wearing their helmets and suits.

Why Quarians still stay protected even on their home world?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Quarians have a very weak immune system, both biologically because their origin planet's has no insect life (I'm not sure how that worked, but that's the lore).

Compounded with several centuries of living on sterile ships made their immune system even weaker, to the point that they require, essentially, self contained biohazard suits.

Putting on and taking off the suits is, in and of itself a dangerous task:

> A quarian who wishes to remove their suit must take antibiotics, immuno-boosters, herbal supplements, or the like in order to do so safely, and even then there are inherent risks

Taking it off just so they can be on their planet is, pretty much, a deadly idea for them.

Edit:
A second reason is: This is a combat mission, they're not just life support suits, they're also combat armor. Why make an expensive combat suit just for one mission?

Source: http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Quarian

Comment: IIRC there was also a comment by Tali somewhere in the game that the suits have become an integral part of Quarian culture, and that they will likely keep wearing them out of habit.

Comment: I think I remember that, though that was for after they'd reclaimed their home world I think?

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Just like the flu. The longer you don't get sick, the worse next time it gets you.